# Processing same keys in json python

Tags: python, json

I'm reading data from a file in the format:

```
{
    "test1" : [7,8,9],
    "test1" : [1,2,3],
    "test2" : [4,5,6]
}
```

I process file with the following code, but it does not account for duplicate keys.

```
with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            data = json.loads(f.read())
```

How to quickly process the presence of the same keys? Are there any libraries or methods?

Comment: In short: you can't because it makes no logical sense *in JSON.* If that's not JSON and there's somehow a different meaning to "key" in your not-JSON format, you need to parse it with some not-JSON parser. Is it not possible to fix the data instead…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code might solve your problem.

```
file = open(path, "r").read()
for key in data.keys():
    new_key = '"{0}" :'.format(key)
    if file.count(new_key) > 1:
       print("ERROR")
```